# How do I connect two collections and get data from an array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm a beginner in the backend (and development in general). Stuck for two weeks with one problem. Therefore, I ask for an expert opinion.
I have collections in Mongo - Order and Items. I generated IDs for them through UUID (I don't know if this info is important or not).

The Order object stores an array of items (items[]) with the id and quantity of a specific item:

```
Order = {
  _id: '123123123123123',
  items: [
    {
      _id: '0001',
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      _id: '0002',
      quantity: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

The Items look like this:

```
Items = [
  {
    _id: '0001',
    title: 'Pizza',
    price: 650,
    description: 'Some text'
  },
  {
    _id: '0002',
    title: 'Pasta',
    price: 500,
    description: 'Some text'
  }
]
```

Question is: **How to get data of Item via id from the array of Items and put it into an Order's Items array with full information about Item and send to the front?** Including title, price, and description.

I tried to use for-loops and forEach - but there was no result. A call to a specific item in Order is working (like this Order.items[0]._id), but in a loop (like this Order.items[i]._id) it gives an error that Order.items[i] is undefined.

Controller:

```
class testController {
    async getTestOrder(req, res) {
        try {
            const id = req.params.id
            const order = await Order.findOne({_id: id})
            const items = await Item.find({})
            for (let i =0; i < order.items.length; i++){
                 for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
                      if(order.items[i]._id === items[j]._id){
                           order.items.push(items[j])      // don't know how to add new data, leaving quantity
                      }
                 }
            }
            res.send(order)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(404).json({message: 'Order was not found'})
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I should get the following response to the front:

```
Order = {
  _id: '123123123123123',
  items: [
    {
      _id: '0001',
      quantity: 1,
      title: 'Pizza',
      price: 650,
      description: 'Some text'
    },
    {
      _id: '0002',
      quantity: 4,
      title: 'Pasta',
      price: 500,
      description: 'Some text'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the `Order.items` array and find out entry from `Items` array based on `_id`. The merge and assign back to `Order.items` object.

```
Order.items.forEach(oi => {
                         let obj = Items.find(i => i._id === oi._id); //find the object  
                         oi = Object.assign(oi,obj); //merge
                     })
```

Comment: IT's working! its a kind of magic))) Thank you, @Rajdeep

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the search for the right item in `items` easier I created a little auxiliary object `itms` (a "hash"), that allows me to access the target item directly:

```js
const order={_id: '123123123123123',items: [{_id: '0001',quantity: 1},{_id: '0002',quantity: 4}]},
  items=[{ _id: '0001',title: 'Pizza', price: 650,description: 'Some text'},{_id: '0002',title: 'Pasta',price: 500,description: 'Some text'}],
  itms={};items.forEach(o=>itms[o._id]=o);

console.log(order.items.map(o=>({quantity:o.quantity,...itms[o._id]})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the items array while iterating over it. If you run your code (for loop) in browser console you'll get 'Uncaught out of memory' error.

Instead of changing items consider to create new items:

```
const result = { // creating new order object
  ...order, // getting all order object props, but overwriting items
  items: order.items.map(orderItem => { // iterating over order.items
    const additionalData = items.find(i => i._id === orderItem._id); // find desired item by _id
    return { // returning a new enriched item
        ...orderItem, // old item props (_id and quantity)
      ...(additionalData || {}) // found item props (title, price and description); Array.find returns null if it finds nothing, so `{}` is a an insurance that we won't spread null value 
    };
  })
}
```